# Validation in Form with React js and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {db} from './firebase'

//I want to add some validation which perform task as follows

//1. Check user enter username less then 40 words

//2. Check user enter email (it need to check basic email information like @ symbol)

//3. Check Message should not be exceed then 400 words ,

// All filed must be filled .

const Contact = () => {

```
const [senderName,setSenderName] = useState("");
const [senderEmail,setSenderEmail] = useState("");
const [senderMessage,setSenderMessage] = useState("");



const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


db.collection('Contact_Form').add({
      User_name:senderName,
      User_email:senderEmail,
      User_message:senderMessage  
    })


 .then(()=>{
        alert("Message submitted")
    })


 .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
    });



    setSenderName("");
    setSenderEmail("");
    setSenderMessage("");
```

};

```
return(


<>
    <div className="contact_us_body">
    <div className="contact_us_container">
    <div className="contact_us_content">
       
    <div className="contact_us_right_side">
    <div className="text_heading">Send us a message</div>
    
    <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}  >
    

        <div className="contact_us_input_box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value={senderName}
            onChange = {(e) => setSenderName(e.target.value)} />
        </div>

        <div className="contact_us_input_box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email"value={senderEmail}
             onChange={(e) => setSenderEmail(e.target.value)} />
        </div>

        <div className="contact_us_input_box message-box">
             <textarea name="messageText" id="" cols="30" rows="10"
             placeholder="Type your Message"value={senderMessage}
             onChange={(e) => setSenderMessage(e.target.value)} >
             </textarea>
        </div>

        <div className="contact_us_button">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Now" />
        </div>

    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 </>
)
```

}

export default Contact;

Answer (score 0):

For Authenticating the Range of characters in username

```
    function stringlength(inputtxt, maxlength)
{ 
var field = inputtxt.value; 
var mxlen = maxlength;

if(field.length> mxlen)
{ 
alert("Please input the userid between " +mnlen+ " and " +mxlen+ " characters");
return false;
}
}
```

If you are using Firebase than you can use firebase Authentication for the login and it will take care of the email formatting-
first of all, define 2 additional useState to show the errors,
*const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');*

```
  const handleLogin = () => {

db
.auth()
.signInWithEmail(email)
.catch((err) =>{
  switch (err.code){
    case "auth/invalid-email":

      // console.log(err)
      setEmailError(err.message);
      break;
        
  }

  
})
```

}

For Limiting the Characters in the  tag, use the following attribute
**`<textarea maxlength="400">`**

Comment: I don't want to authenticate passwords and emails... I just use this code in my contact us form where I have Username, Its email, and its message so I want that if user wants to send a message through the contact us then username, email and message field must be field and email shout taken symbols and username not exceed then 40 words then only my form will be submitted.

Comment: You can add the 'required' attribute in the input tag to make it mandatory for the user to fill these inputs.  e.g     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value={senderName}
            onChange = {(e) => setSenderName(e.target.value)}   required    />,

Comment: Check the updated answer, you can simply remove the password part.